# Add element from set of strings to vector of set of strings

Tags: c++, vector, set, emplace

I want to do an operation for the below exercise, where I'm trying to add an element from a set of strings to a vector of sets of strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::set<std::string> remaining_cards = {"2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S"};
    std::vector<std::set<const std::string>> player_cards;

    int random_number;
    random_number=2;

    auto it = remaining_cards.cbegin();
    std::advance(it, random_number);
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
      // add one element to a vector of sets of strings from set of strings
    player_cards.emplace_back(*it);
    // remove that element from the original set
    remaining_cards.erase(it);

    return 0;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why do I get the error `::const_reference = const std::basic_string<char>&]' cannot be overloaded.`
2. I tried to remove the `const` from the `player_cards` declaration but then I get `no matching function for call to 'std::set<std::basic_string<char> >::set(const std::basic_string<char>&)`
3. When I do `emplace_back(*it);` does `it` have to be dereferenced?
4. I suspect that my issues arise from the fact that I try to put an element of a set into a vector of sets of strings. Do I need to create a set first of the element that the iterator points to? I assume it only points to a string.
5. Does emplace_back not have the ability to create a set directly?
6. Could I do something like `emplace_back(std::set(*it));`

It's possible that all the above may be conceptually wrong as I'm new to c++, but I'm trying to understand what's the best way to add an element from a set to a vector of sets. It seems more complicated than expected.

Comment: `std::set<const std::string>` -- [Try and add a string to that container](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdc2efa0a1c510e4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no constructor in the class template `std::set` that accepts a reference to an object of the type value_type. But there is a constructor that accepts for example an initializer list. You could write

```
player_cards.emplace_back( std::set<std::string>( { *it } ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why do I get the error `::const_reference = const std::basic_string<char>&]' cannot be overloaded.`

Because you are trying to use a set of const. Const types don't satisfy the type requirements of `std::set`. Use `std::vector<std::set<std::string>>` instead.

> 2. I tried to remove the const from the player_cards declaration but then I get `no matching function for call to 'std::set<std::basic_string<char> >::set(const std::basic_string<char>&)`

`it` is an iterator that points to a `std::string`. If you take a look at the constructors of `std::set`, you'll find that it has no constructor that would take a string as an argument.

There is a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with `emplace_back` directly for convoluted reasons. But it can be used with a helper variable:

```
auto init = {*it};
player_cards.emplace_back(init);
```

> 3. When I do `emplace_back(*it);` does it have to be dereferenced?

Given that neither `emplace_back(*it);` nor `emplace_back(it);` work, this question is a bit unclear. You have to indirect through an iterator to access the pointed element. If you don't need to access the pointed element, then you don't need to indirect through the iterator.

> 4. ... Do I need to create a set first of the element that the iterator points to?

That's what the `emplace_back` does.